# how to use zcat without the warning when using pipe

Tags: linux, bash, compression, ksh, zcat

I'm trying to silent zcat warning through the `option -q or 2>/dev/null`
so far nothing is working. I keep getting the same warning when a file name is missing.
I'm looping through 100s of compressed files to extract a specific data. The  idea is if zcat  encounter a bad name or a missing file name, zcat will just stay quite and wait for the next cycle, but currently this is what I'm getting when using both options

> zcat -q  $ram | head -n1    or    zcat $ram | head -n1  2>/dev/null

```
gzip: compressed data not read from a terminal. Use -f to force decompression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

Any idea how to solve that or a faster way to read a .gz file with a silent feature that works?

Thanks

Comment: `2>/dev/null` should work, and works fine for me from the command line. If this is from a script, can you edit your post to include a few lines of context?

Comment: sorry I updated the question I forgot to add the pipe. Yes!!! without it , it will work, but when I try to use pipe, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, you're redirecting only stderr from `head`; you're not redirecting from `zcat` at all. If you want to redirect stderr from `zcat`, then you need to put the redirection *before* the pipe symbol, like so:

```
zcat $ram 2>/dev/null | head -n1
```

Comment: thanks  for the advice I will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

Unset the GZIP env var:

```
$ gunzip    --stdout    *.log.gz | gzip --stdout - > x
gzip: warning: GZIP environment variable is deprecated; use an alias or script
gzip: warning: GZIP environment variable is deprecated; use an alias or script
$ echo $GZIP
-9
$ unset GZIP
$ gunzip --stdout *.log.gz | gzip --stdout - > x
$
```

This has the benefit over redirect stderr of still showing any other errors.